# Use only one column of array as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have a very large array of data:

```
double matrix[100000][100] = {0.0};
```

During runtime this data is updated. Now I want to give the reference to this data to a function FUNC. However, I want to only give one column to the function FUNC, like:

```
FUNC(matrix["all elements"]["only column with index 5"]);
```

and not the entire array. Furthermore, I dont want to perform a copy operation before (because this is slow), I just want to give the pointer or reference to the specific rows/columns inside the large array data. The function should only see an array like:

```
void FUNC(double* array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
         doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

How do I do give this partial data from array "matrix" to the function FUNC?

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You'd have to write a class that exposes multiple forms of indexing. There's no built-in way to go "against the grain" with just an array of arrays. So your options are to pass in a reference to the whole thing and only use what you need, or come up with some kind of custom iterator that acts on columns, or something like that.

Comment: you can pass the whole array by pointer and then only access the part you need inside the function.

Comment: Whoa, I didnt expect that this is not possible. I was under the impression that I just cut out some part of the data (like in MATLAB...).

Comment: Array elements are located next to each other in the memory. This is the defining property of an array. Elements of a column are not located next to each other in the memory. Therefore they do not form an array and you cannot access them with a lone pointer. So (1) pass a column of a 2D array (2) as a `double*` (3) with no copying — pick any two.

Comment: It is not (yet) possible, it is being worked on. Though maybe slightly different then what you are used to. [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFCLmQEkPUw). For reference [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) C++23. In a way you make a small proxy object that does all the address calculations for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column values of your matrix are not sequential in memory, so you can't pass a single column to `FUNC()` without making a copy of the data into a sequential array. However, if you are able to add the column index as an additional parameter to `FUNC()` then you can do something like this instead:

```
const int MAX_ROWS = ...;
const int MAX_COLS = ...;

using Matrix = double[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

void doSomething(double value)
{
    ...
}

void FUNC(const Matrix& matrix, int column)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row) {
         doSomething(matrix[row][column]);
    }
}
```

```
Matrix matrix = {};
...
FUNC(matrix, 5);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/8vINAG)